# I had a dream with a jin

Tags: jinn

First off I have to say that I am not a muslim. I'm an orthodox Christian.

Some time ago I dreamt that I was in my bedroom and there was something like a ghost that I could sense, I was feeling comfortable and protected like i had some kind of relationship with it. Then I saw he was writing things that i cannot remember now in walls and in small pieces of paper. Then I saw him in front of me as a big smoky shadow; then I woke up.

A muslim friend has told me kayer after I saw this dream that it probably was a jinn. I knew nothing about jinns before he mentioned them. Never heard of them. Since then I have dreamt of many random things every night. Also I often hear noises at night such as knocking from a closet in my room etc. Since I was younger I could feel the presence of someone invisible.

Some facts are about me ar : I am a loner. I have some kind of social anxiety and when I'm in a crowd out with friends etc I feel I want to run away to go home. I took almost 2 years to get into a relationship. Since young I had a luck with money or things I wanted. Whenever I ask for something for a help etc I always get it. It's kind of creepy. It's like I have everything but alone. Well I don't have a particular question but I don't know much about jinns and islam so if anyone is interested in telling me about my case please do so.

Also ı want to add that since the age of 5 I was having nightmares like I'm getting killed. I have seen them many times. Like shooting me and waking up thinking I was shot in soul and I need yo get in the hospital or train would run over me or watching my self dead.

Comment: In Quran you will get to see a whole Chapter named on Jinn (Surat Al-Jinn) http://quran.com/72 and its existence is truth ,they can see us and they have families like us ,, we are not able to see them but some of us have special qualities who could see them but its not easy thing to do ,,some of my realtive is dealing with it and they could reallly feel its presence could hear noises and also in dreams but like humans they have some good jinns and some bads but its not good to make some realtions with them not everyone could easily bear this.

Answer (score 2):

This is sleep paralysis. I've had many of these dreams where i would feel this presence that you're speaking about and wouldn't be able to move or wake up for as long as a minute. Basically it has to do with hallucinations and REM cycles during sleep. Nothing to do with jinns.
Research into it and you'll see that many of your hallucinations are explained.

Comment: Mm i could move. I rememebr also wondering around the bed. I woke up fine .

Comment: Also i added about some dreams i had.